# How do I change an object's value in an IndexedDB index?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Is it possible to update an object's value within an IndexedDB index without cloning, deleting, or putting a new entry? Theoretically something like the following snippet would do the trick, though it probably would not `delete` until the `put` was confirmed. But it looks like overkill to me. It looks like it would be a nightmare to do any error handling on.

```js
const objectStore = db.transaction([objectStoreName], 'readwrite')
  .objectStore(objectStoreName);

const requestGet = objectStore.get(index);
requestGet.onsuccess = (event: any) => {
  const value = event.target.result.value // Store old value
  const requestDelete = objectStore.delete(index);
  requestDelete.onsuccess = (event: any) => {
    const requestPut = objectStore
      .put({index: 'New Index Value', value: value}); // Put back using new index         
  };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly change values in an object store's index. You can change the values of an object in an object store, and IndexedDB will propagate your changes to related indices. Indices are essentially read-only.

Comment: In my use case I've got objects stored like `{name: string, value: any}` as the application requires all the names to be unique. So I thought that "name" would work as an index. Sounds like I've made a bad and I need to split the name and index value up `{index: ID, name: string, value: any}` :(

Answer (score 0):

It is possible since you specify your index, otherwise, an other logic may be necessary.

As you should know, the **IDBObjectStore** has a method **.put()** which it will receive two params. With it you can either PUT a new value or UPDATE a value.

IDBObjectStore.put(item, key)
item: The item you want to put/update
key: **opcional**: Your primary object store key (such as an uuid, a random number, in short...) for that item you would like to update.

Code:

```js
//This is an example only.
    //Let's think that we have an object store into our IndexDB 'user', where object store is called by user-data: 
    //#  Key              Value
    //0   1     { username: 'John Doe' } 

    //Here, we are receiving the 'success' result from an indexedDB.open(), and using its result with a promise.
    dbPromise.then(db => {
            //Getting the transaction
            const transaction = db.transaction('user-data', 'readwrite')
            //Getting the objectStore with the data, the same object store before.
            const store = transaction.objectStore('user-data')
            //Getting the key's object store, in the other other words, this is the key you define when you create you objectStore, with createObjectStore. In this example, I've used 'autoIncrement: true'
            const query = store.get(1)
            
            //Getting the query result with a success listener.
            query.addEventListener('success', event => {
                const { ['result']: user } = event.target
                user.productsIntoCart.push(newItem)
                
                //With this, we will be able to change the object store value.  
                user.username = 'Jane Doe'
                store.put(user, 1)
            })
            query.addEventListener('error', event => console.error(event))
            transaction.addEventListener('complete', () => db.close())
        })
        
    //#  Key              Value
    //0   1     { username: 'Jane Doe' }
```

You can see more details you want in the MDN IDBObjectStore.put documentation.
[IDBObjectStore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/put)